# Open word document from codebehind - e.g Response.Write with some javascript

Tags: sharepoint

In a custom application page I modify a file (word doc), then i call SPFile.CheckOut();

Then I would like to open that file directly in edit modus in word . (As it would have been if the user clicked the file and selected "Edit in Microsoft Office Word" )

Any ideas on how to do that?

EDIT: Yes, I know I can't to this on the server. I'm looking for a way to return some javascript that will open the doc on the client. (I guess there is some javascript built in the checks for the precense of a Office AcitiveX, and then calls it)

Larsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did some investigation with Firebug and found this attached to the "Edit in Microsoft Word" link.

```
<span type="option" text="Edit in Microsoft Office Word" onmenuclick="editDocumentWithProgID2('/sites/I2Validation/KitTestSite/Kits%20Test%20Site%20Documents/Here%20is%20Kit.doc', '', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', '0', 'http://servername/sites/I2Validation/KitTestSite', '0')" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/icdoc.gif" iconalttext="" sequence="240" id="ID_EditIn_Microsoft Office Word"/>
```

I'm thinking you could probably programmatically call `editDocumentWithProgID2()` after the page has loaded.

Found this in core.js:

```
function editDocumentWithProgID2(strDocument, varProgID, varEditor, bCheckout,strhttpRoot, strCheckouttolocal)
{
    var errorCode=editDocumentWithProgIDNoUI(strDocument, varProgID, varEditor, bCheckout,strhttpRoot, strCheckouttolocal);
    if (errorCode==1)
    {
        alert(L_EditDocumentRuntimeError_Text);
        window.onfocus=RefreshOnNextFocus;
    }
    else if (errorCode==2)
        alert(L_EditDocumentProgIDError_Text);
}
```

Comment: @Kit - did you do this within a Share Point site, or an external site?  I'm asking because I need similar functionality but from an external site linking into a Share Point document library.

Comment: @RichardB It won't work on an external site because this is referencing JavaScript that is included by default only on SharePoint pages.

Comment: ah.  the root of our issue wound up being a disabled plugin from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really possibly, mainly because the codebehind runs on the server while you want the client's machine to open word.  The best you could do is sent up a meta refresh with the URL of the word document - when hit the user's browser would open the file.

http://sharepoint/sp.doc">

A quick warning: make sure that you check the file out as the current user otherwise your non-admin users will not have rights to open the file.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I've updated the question for better understanding. 
BTW, I thought that running the site with Integrated security SPFile.Checkout() would execute with current users privileges?

Answer (score 0):

As UJ says you cannot open it in word on the server.

But you can edit the document on the server using open xml. see : http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

In order to edit the document on the server you without any code, you need to install the Microsoft Office Wep Apps